# Подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое:

Tags: html, phpstorm

- suppress all for file
- suppress for file
- suppress for tag?

Это функции из редактора PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Это функции отключения показа ошибок. См. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections

Обратите внимание, что таким образом можно только отключить показ ошибок и предупреждений от inspections. Синтаксические ошибки от парсера отключить нельзя